# Pandas: searchsorted on a list field on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df with a sorted list int column like this:

```
>>> test
                          timestamp  
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  
1  [1, 3, 5, 7]  
2  [2, 4, 6, 8]  
3  [1, 5, 5, 5]  
4  [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to look for the element earlier to a constant value. Basically, if passing the constant value 5, I should get a df additional column like this:

```
res
3
1
2
0
1
```

I'm trying with searchsorted, but I'm not able to make it work:

```
test['res'] =  np.searchsorted(test['timestamp'][test.index] , 5)
...
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

If I pass the actual column, it works with the index 0:

```
np.searchsorted(test['timestamp'][0] , 5)
3
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to pass the correct index in to make it work:

```
test['res'] =  np.searchsorted(test['timestamp'][test.index] , 5)
...
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Also put the index on a column `x`, and tried referencing it like this to no avail:

```
test['x'] = test.index
test['res'] =  np.searchsorted(test['timestamp'][test['x']] , 5)
...
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

How can I use searchsorted in this scenario?

Comment: shouldn't the result be `[4, 2, 2, 1, 2]`

Comment: Actually the result should be the one I put in there, so I have to substract 1 to the searchsorted result if > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're simply looking for [pd.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp':[
        [1, 2, 3, 4],  
        [1, 3, 5, 7], 
        [2, 4, 6, 8],
        [1, 5, 5, 5],
        [3, 4, 5, 6]
    ]})

df['res'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: np.searchsorted(x, 5))

print(df)
```

Output

```
      timestamp  res
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]    4
1  [1, 3, 5, 7]    2
2  [2, 4, 6, 8]    2
3  [1, 5, 5, 5]    1
4  [3, 4, 5, 6]    2
```

Comment: Just as an addition Chris - why it wouldn't work in the previous approach? It's not clear to me why it works with a literal int but not with an int from a column. Thanks!